# Permitir acesso a uma URL apenas por redirecionamento

Tags: php

Bom... Isso pode soar estranho, mas preciso bloquear o acesso direto a uma url dentro de meu servidor, liberando ela apenas quando o usuário for redirecionado de uma outra pagina especifica.

Esse seria o esquema que estou tentando imagina:

O usuário acessa essa pagina: meusite.com/home.php?id=xxxxxxx
Nessa pagina terá um botão DOWNLOAD, e ao clicar nela o usuário será levado para: meusite.com/dl.php?id=xxxxxxx

Assim, só quero que ele tenha acesso ao */dl.php se for atravez da */home.php
Existe alguma forma de fazer isso?

Comment: com php puro ou algum framework? o que você já tem pronto?

Comment: PHP puro, o servidor só aceita php puro. Só tenho as paginas mesmo, já pesquisei sobre isso aqui e na comunidade EN, mas não encontrei nada. Então não tenho nada.

Comment: dá uma olhada [aqui](https://medium.com/the-andela-way/how-to-build-a-basic-server-side-routing-system-in-php-e52e613cf241), é um tutorial de como fazer um sistema básico de roteamento em php

Comment: Certo. Vou analisar e retorno com o feedback.

Comment: Gera e envia um hash pela url e no endpoint tu válida esse hash. Depois de um tempo tu inválida o hash pra não poder ser mais acessado direto. Melhor que isso tu pode usa um json web token (gera um token que será válido por um determiando tempo).

Answer (score -1):

Se for só com programação, você pode usar algo com a "variavel global" $_SESSION. Com exceção da página que dá permissão, coloque nas demais um comando parecido com esse:

```
$_SESSION['permitir_download'] = 0;
```

E, quando for a página que tem a permissão:

```
$_SESSION['permitir_download'] = 1;
```

Na página de download, faça algo assim:

```
if ($_SESSION['permitir_download']):
//...Download
     $_SESSION['permitir_download'] = 0;
else:
//...Sem permissão 
     $_SESSION['permitir_download'] = 0;
     die();
endif;
```

Acho que pode ajudar.

Abraços.

Answer (score -2):

Uma solução bem elegante é você verificar o $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].
Sempre que uma pagina PHP é carregada por uma chamada GET ou POST, ele carrega esse dado com o endereço de origem. Assim você pode criar um comportamento para responder ao $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], de acordo com suas necessidades.

Comment: Esse **sempre** não é verdade. É **comum** os navegadores preencherem esse cabeçalho, mas não é obrigatório; e vale lembrar que uma requisição pode ser feita a partir de outras fontes, que a requisição é escrita manualmente, podendo definir o valor do cabeçalho como esperado, mesmo que não tenha sido redirecionado. Pode ser uma solução, mas não é nada confiável.